# How to access an element from a function output in a list?

Tags: python, list

I want to access the value of 'zipcode' in the output that's being returned as part of a predefined function called uszipcode. But I am not sure how do I go about it? Any ideas?

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=False)
result = search.by_coordinates(44.102665, -121.300797, radius=10, returns=5)
print(result)
```

**The output comes out like this:**

[SimpleZipcode(zipcode='97701', zipcode_type='Standard', major_city='Bend', post_office_city='Bend, OR', common_city_list=['Bend'], county='Deschutes County', state='OR', lat=44.0, lng=-121.3, timezone='Pacific', radius_in_miles=37.0, area_code_list=['458', '541'], population=58993, population_density=87.0, land_area_in_sqmi=678.9, water_area_in_sqmi=5.25, housing_units=27682, occupied_housing_units=24589, median_home_value=285300, median_household_income=53444, bounds_west=-121.977954, bounds_east=-120.747881, bounds_north=44.328125, bounds_south=43.752828)]

I want to access the value of zipcode inside SimpleZipcode which is '97701'.

Comment: What is `type(result)` ?

Comment: @Austin It is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like results is an array of SimpleZipcode objeact. So you can probably access the zipcode you are interested  via

```
result[0].zipcode
```

This returns the very first zipcode item in the array of zipcodes returned

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that since you're basically *searching* or *filtering*, you could possibly get a handful of results.
Your query returns a list (or rather an array) of zipcodes.

Since your specific query returns a list that contains one object, you could simply get it by:
`print(result[0].zipcode)`

Read more about it in the documentation: https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/index.html#example-usage

> **Search by Latitude and Longitude**
>   You can search all zipcode with-in range of XXX miles from a coordinate. You can add returns=xxx to set maximum number of zipcode can be returned. By default, it’s 5. Use returns=0 to remove the limit. **The results are sorted by the distance from the center, from lowest to highest.**
>
> > > result = search.by_coordinates(39.122229, -77.133578, radius=30)
> > >
> > > len(res) # by default 5 results returned
> > >
> > > 5
> > >
> > > for zipcode in result:
> > >
> > > ...     # do whatever you want...
> > >
> > > result = search.by_coordinates(39.122229, -77.133578, radius=100, returns=None)
> > >
> > > len(result) # the return limit is removed
> > >       3531

Comment: Thank you very much @Ziv. This helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

result=result.values() should change the string to a list

so something like

```
result=result.values()
zipcode=result[0]
```

should get it done

Comment: This may have worked with pandas but my output is coming out in the form of a list.